# Rabbitmq cluster, when the node is offline, how to ensure that the offline queue receives messages from the fanout exchange?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have three node cluster, and two queues bound to one fanout exchange. My requirement is that all messages sent to the exchange must be saved to these two queues, all messages cannot be lost and must be processed.

When one of the nodes is offline, the queue on the node will lose the message received by the exchange. I may be able to use Quorum Queues, but this can only allow one node to go offline. If two nodes are offline, the same problem will occur. Is there any solution?

**Update:** (2023-10-03)

I want to describe my problem in detail, queue-A and queue-B are bound to MyFanoutExchange, and queue-A is located at node rabbitmq-1, queue-B is located at node rabbitmq-2. Now, all messages sent to MyFanoutExchange will go to queue-A and queue-B, which is good.

| Exchange | Status | Nodes | Queues |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MyFanoutExchange | online | rabbitmq-0 |  |
|  | online | rabbitmq-1 | queue-A |
|  | online | rabbitmq-2 | queue-B |

When node rabbitmq-1 is offline, all messages sent to MyFanoutExchange will go to queue-B but not queue-A, even if rabbitmq-1 comes online later.

| Exchange | Status | Nodes | Queues |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MyFanoutExchange | online | rabbitmq-0 |  |
|  | offline | <del>rabbitmq-1</del> | <del>queue-A</del> |
|  | online | rabbitmq-2 | queue-B |

I need to ensure that queue-A and queue-B can receive all messages from MyFanoutExchange.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use one direct queue. Then, your 3 nodes will process messages one by one, and that will be faster. Also, you can create a recerve queue for messages with mistakes using these headers:

```
async function initBaseQueues(
  ch: amqplib.Channel,
  hash: Record<string, string>,
) {
  const queues = Object.keys(hash);

  await ch.assertExchange(FACTORY_GATEWAY_EXCHANGE, 'direct');

  for (let i = 0; i < queues.length; i++) {
    const queue = queues[i];

    const routingKey = hash[queue];

    await ch.assertQueue(queue, {
      autoDelete: false,
      durable: true,
      arguments: {
        [ERabbitQueueArguments.deadLetterExchange]:
          FACTORY_GATEWAY_EXCHANGE + RETRY_CONST,
        [ERabbitQueueArguments.deadLetterRoutingKey]: routingKey + RETRY_CONST,
      },
    });

    await ch.bindQueue(queue, FACTORY_GATEWAY_EXCHANGE, routingKey);

    Logger.log(`Queue ${queue} initialized`);
  }
}

async function initRetryQueues(
  ch: amqplib.Channel,
  hash: Record<string, string>,
) {
  const queues = Object.keys(hash);

  await ch.assertExchange(FACTORY_GATEWAY_EXCHANGE + RETRY_CONST, 'direct');

  for (let i = 0; i < queues.length; i++) {
    const queue = queues[i];

    const routingKey = hash[queue];

    await ch.assertQueue(queue + RETRY_CONST, {
      autoDelete: false,
      durable: true,
      arguments: {
        [ERabbitQueueArguments.deadLetterExchange]: FACTORY_GATEWAY_EXCHANGE,
        [ERabbitQueueArguments.deadLetterRoutingKey]: routingKey,
        [ERabbitQueueArguments.messageTTL]: REQUEUE_DEALAY_CONST,
      },
    });

    await ch.bindQueue(
      queue + RETRY_CONST,
      FACTORY_GATEWAY_EXCHANGE + RETRY_CONST,
      routingKey + RETRY_CONST,
    );

    Logger.log(`Queue ${queue + RETRY_CONST} initialized`);
  }
}

export default async function initRabbitQueues() {
  const conn = await amqplib.connect(
    process.env.RABBIT_HOST ?? 'amqp://localhost:5672',
  );

  const ch1 = await conn.createChannel();

  const hash = queueNames();

  await initBaseQueues(ch1, hash);

  await initRetryQueues(ch1, hash);

  await conn.close();
}
```

The headers are:

```
export enum ERabbitQueueArguments {
  deadLetterExchange = 'x-dead-letter-exchange',
  deadLetterRoutingKey = 'x-dead-letter-routing-key',
  messageTTL = 'x-message-ttl',
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. I think when the node is offline, the message does not go to Dead Letter Exchanges, will this solve my problem?

Comment: If your node on queue is ofline messages will just stay and accumulate in the queue, if you have correctly configurated it. When your node will be up it will process all messages, wich the queue has been accumulated. It is main idea of RabbitMQ =) To Dead Letter Exchange messages will go if you "nack" message in your code) I think jour problem is that you configure queues to auto delete. If auto delete is on, than the queue will be deleted with all messages, when last concumer goes offline. So just set your queues to ```auto-delete = false``` =)

Comment: I have disabled auto-delete, I think the problem is that the queue here loses messages received by exchange when node 1 is offline, but the queue on node 2 is working fine.